# How to addclassname for even posts in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with nextjs and i am trying to fetch list of images,I want to add class(using if else condition)
I want for even post i want to add className "mt10"

Here is my code

```
{this.state.books.map((book, index) => {
    const isEven = index % 2 === 0
    console.log('data is '+ isEven);
    return 
        (
            <div className="col-md-4 {isEven }  forbcol">
                <div className="bookimg">
                <img src="img/forbes.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
         )
   })}
```

Comment: @AhmadFaraz: its showing "<div class="{col-md-4 ${isEven} forbcol}">" in my inspect element, means showing statically instead of dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{this.state.books.map((book, index) => {
return 
    (
        <div className={`col-md-4 ${index % 2 === 0 ? 'mt10' : '' } forbcol`}>
            <div className="bookimg">
            <img src="img/forbes.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
     )
})}
```

Comment: not working for me showing statically code instead of dynamic in console.log

Comment: Sorry I missed the dollar sign, in the template string condition, I just update the answer, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

```
{this.state.books.map((book, index) => {
    const isEven = index % 2 === 0
    console.log('data is '+ isEven);
const style = {`col-md-4 ${isEven }  forbcol`}

    return 
        (
            <div className={style}>
                <div className="bookimg">
                <img src="img/forbes.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
         )
   })}
```

Comment: i am getting following error


Unexpected token ```. Expected identifier, string literal, numeric literal or [ for the computed key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).